# Расширение QTableView по контенту

Tags: c++, qt

Есть `QTableView`, нужно чтобы ее размеры подгонялись по размеру содержимого. Но не флаг `Stretch` в хедерах.

[image: окно]

Comment: "Нужно чтобы размеры ячеек были статичными, а сама таблица увеличивалась."
Я не уверен, что понял как это. Но попробуй покурить в сторону sizeHintRole для data и headerData модели.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте настроить у заголовка таблицы:
[tableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html)->[horizontalHeader()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#horizontalHeader)->[setResizeMode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#setResizeMode)([QHeaderView::ResizeToContents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum))

Тот же код, но без ссылок:

```
tableView->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents)
```

Comment: Это не совсем то. Так он просто подгоняет размер хедеров по контенту. А нужно, чтобы он еще сам виджет подгонял по размеру хедеров

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg Понятно... как неудобно будет с ним работать..

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg, я вот думаю можно коннектиться к сигналу заголовка geometriesChanged(), брать у заголовка его ширину (или размер всех секций/столбцов) и задавать таблице это как фиксированную ширину

Comment: @gi9red Логично, но почему-то мне кажется, что обязательно должно быть решение стандартными методами, но спасибо, приму к сведению